# Why is it preferred to have non-virtual interfaces?

Tags: c++, interface

I am going through this article http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm by Herb Sutter. The author mentions that writing non-virtual interfaces separates the interface specification from the "implementation details (namely the internally customizable behavior)"

```
// Example 1: A traditional base class.
//
class Widget
{
public:
  // Each of these functions might optionally be
  // pure virtual, and if so might or might not have
  // an implementation in Widget; see Item 27 in [1].
  //
  virtual int Process( Gadget& );
  virtual bool IsDone();
  // ...
};
```

What kind of implementation detail (or customizable behavior) does the above example specify? I am slightly confused about what is wrong with the above code, which requires us to have non-virtual interfaces

Answer (score 1):

By `customizable behavior` it means the implementation provided by different `Derived Classes`, i.e the classes which will derive from your `Interface`.

Consider this:

```
class IMachine
{
    public:
        int ProcessJob()
        {
            cout << "Processing Job in By-Default way" << endl;
        }
        virtual int ProcessOrder()
        {
            cout << "Processing Order in By-Default way" << endl;
        }
};
class CMachine_A : public IMachine
{
    public:
        int ProcessJob()
        {
            cout << "Processing Job in Machine A's way" << endl;
        }
        int ProcessOrder()
        {
            cout << "Processing Order in Machine A's way" << endl;
        }
};
class CMachine_B : public IMachine
{
    public:
        int ProcessJob()
        {
            cout << "Processing Job in Machine B's way" << endl;
        }
        int ProcessOrder()
        {
            cout << "Processing Order in Machine B's way" << endl;
        }
};

IMachine *pMachine;
CMachine_A oMachineA;
CMachine_B oMachineB;

pMachine = &oMachineA;
pMachine->ProcessJob();
pMachine = &oMachineB;
pMachine->ProcessJob();

Output:
Processing Job in By-Default way
Processing Job in By-Default way
```

So, in above example even though `pMachine` points to different concrete implementations (read: derived classes), the output is same irrespective of chosen implementation/derived class. That is, the `customizable behavior` of Machine A and Machine B is not coming in-effect or not honored. So, by having **non virtual** `IMachine::ProcessJob()`, the interface `IMachine` has separated/ignored/suppressed the way in which the Job will get processed irrespective of the type of Machine (`CMachine_A` or `CMachine_B`) which is used.

Now consider this:

```
IMachine *pMachine;
CMachine_A oMachineA;
CMachine_B oMachineB;

pMachine = &oMachineA;
pMachine->ProcessOrder();
pMachine = &oMachineB;
pMachine->ProcessOrder();

Output:
Processing Order in Machine A's way
Processing Order in Machine B's way
```

Here, when `pMachine` points to different concrete implementations (read: derived classes), the output is according to the chosen implementation/derived class. That is, the `customizable behavior` of Machine A and Machine B is coming in-effect or honored. So, by having **virtual** `IMachine::ProcessOrder()`, the interface `IMachine` has kept the option/way open in which the Order will get processed depending upon the type of Machine (`CMachine_A` or `CMachine_B`) which is used.

In short, since the interface `IMachine` has kept the `ProcessOrder` as `virtual` therefore different implementation/derived class can provide `customizable behavior` for the function `ProcessOrder`.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the virtual public interface, `int Process( Gadget& );`, you are also restricting the extension interface to match this public interface. Whoever extends this class will need to do this by implementing the `Process` function.

Providing a cleaner public interface and a more suitable [batch] of well designed private functions for customization will allow tackling our two goals individually.