# What does "it's better to not let publicly derived classes also customize the inherited interface" mean?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, solid-principles

Edit : 
This question have been marked as duplicate of [Why is it preferred to have non-virtual interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872978/why-is-it-preferred-to-have-non-virtual-interfaces).

This https://stackoverflow.com/a/37876945/4450986 answer only points out that not using the `virtual` tag makes the function resolve as the base class's one if you cast it as the base class.

---

In this [website](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm), it is suggested to always redirect method override through a concrete method call redirecting to a (maybe pure) virtual function, arguing :

> *it's better to not let publicly derived classes also customize the inherited interface*

and accordingly

```
class Widget
{
public:
    int Process( Gadget& ); // uses DoProcess...()

private:
    virtual int DoProcessPhase1( Gadget& );
    virtual int DoProcessPhase2( Gadget& );
};
```

Nb: the destructor is kept for later in the argumentation, and thus not detailed here.

How does defining a public virtual method as an interface allow the user to customize the inherited interface ?

I think this kind of redirection makes the class unclear about how it should be used and extended, especially when included code induces convention-based code (`do_function_name`) that could be something else for anybody (eg another company which would use the convention `concrete_function_name` or whatever)

Furthermore, if it needs process1, 2 and three, it looks like it has more than one responsability, which breaks the first SOLID principle.

Comment: If the processing **must** happen in two stages and in that order, then what is stopping a derived class from breaking that order when completely overriding `Process`? The non-virtual interface is there to maintain an invariant.

Comment: Then, what is the responsability of the class, make sure the processing is called in the correct order, or defining an interface for what the processing should be like ?

Comment: I would like to point out that other question isn't marked as answered, by the way.

Comment: Both. The interface is non virtual, and maintains a guarantee.

Comment: It therefore breaks the single responsibilty principle.

Comment: That is a fault of the person who asked it. The provided answer is still on point.

Comment: I'm looking for an online compiler to respond that haha

Comment: Breaking a solid principle, is it? I would argue that rolling an implicit invariant onto every derived class is a much worse violation. The invariant belongs in the base.

Comment: I just say break that into two classes, not forget about requirements.

Comment: So, in the sentence "So, in above example even though pMachine points to different concrete implementations (read: derived classes), the output is same irrespective of chosen implementation/derived class." If the code is not marked as virtual, it is default behaviour. So it doesn't make any point.

Comment: Your designs will suffer if you treat guidelines as dogma. Bloating a class heirarchy for an artificial reason is a no no in my book. But if you wish to elaborate on this, try [SoftwareEngineering.se]